# Error alert only showing the first 20 characters. Dynaweb on IIS

Tags: iis

I have an old dynaweb project, deployed on IIS, that I have recently migrated to a new windows server. The error alerts are not showing the whole error message. The engine code was copied as is.

What could be causing this?

**Old setup**

```
Microsoft windows server 2003.

32 Bit.
```

[image]

**New setup**

```
Windows server 2016 standard
64 Bit.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.15000.23
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    13.0.1601.5
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                            6.3.14393
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any related error messages in the event viewer? Do you have enable 32-bit Applications in iis? if not, you need to configure IIS to run 32-bit applications. 1. Open IIS 2. Go to current server – > Application Pools 3. Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under 4. Click Advanced setting or Application Pool Default
5. Set Enable 32-bit Applications to True

Comment: thanks @samwu. I'll try that.

Comment: I tried that but it made the whole menu stop working.

Comment: Did you get any error messages?